# Border HBox JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Есть изображения, которые лежат в `HBox`. При наведении мышки срабатывает метод который вокруг `HBox` прорисовывает рамку `hbox.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 2pt; -fx-border-color: red")`. Как сделать чтобы прорисовывалась не рамка, а просто подчеркивался `HBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы добиться эффекта подчёркивания - нужно указать ширину только нижней рамки для **HBox**:
`-fx-border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;`

**Источник:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/10329951/2506123